# Run simple xterm command at desktop start

Tags: boot, terminal

I've been searching for this for hours, really hoping someone could help me out here.

We're using a raspberry pi for digital signage, and I just want to run pianobar (runs in a terminal) behind it for music. Doing that works easy enough, BUT I want to have the pianobar terminal minimized, so if the signage program crashes for any reason, the wallpaper (just the company logo) is showing behind it, making a nice, clean display in all situations.

I just want to run `xterm -e 'sleep 5 && pianobar -iconic'` automatically when the desktop loads, and also keep the terminal open and minimized, but every method I've tried to run at startup fails. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

I've tried bashrc, rc.local (obviously didn't work how I wanted) and a few autorun scripts from lxterminal, and a .desktop autorun script and I couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: You can follow [my answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/launch-a-gui-tkinter-program-on-boot) and replace the command line in `ExecStart`

Comment: With that, you can also create another service where 'your first service is require' and then simulate keyboard shortcut (with third tools) for the Minimize keyboard shortcut of xterm in this specific service. Also you can write bash script containing all your steps and then create only one service.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run this from an xterm (the only things which require that are TUI apps), which would solve part of the problem.